# Deploying my first play app, i'm so lost

Tags: deployment, playframework

I've decided to go with Apache as the http server in front of my play app. The server team at my company says they installed Apache and Python and play on the target server. I'm code complete, so here's where I don't know what to do next.

1. How do i "compile" my play java app?
2. What folders do I deploy, which ones do I not deploy?
3. Where on the target server hard drive do I place the webapp I'm deploying?
4. How do i tell apache where I deployed the play webapp to on the disk?
5. How do I make it so that apache and play are now always running and don't require I be logged in on the target server?
6. Yeah I'm new to linux
7. Please help I'm lost.

Thanks in advance
Josh

Comment: I copied my files over, and i exported the path to include /opt/play-1.2.3, then I sudo then I typed play start /z/www/docs/myapp

Comment: then it started the play app, but I can't leave it running like this, I want to use chkconfig play on to add play to the startup list, but chkconfig doesn't recognize the play command. I found a play script to put inside the init.d folder, but it requires you bind play to one specific app, which sucks, I want to be able to run lots of play apps on my web server. Whats the point of a webserver that can only run one website. So I need to figure this all out. Also my app requires a dependent jar file, where is a good place to put those?

Comment: This is the file I found, (http://www.playframework.org/community/snippets/12). But this limits my play installation to one app. This can't be right. There has got to be another way to --add play to chkconfig without needing this file right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [Preparing for production](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/production) section before anything else.

**How do i "compile" my play java app?**

Play does that for you when you laucnh **play start**. However you can use the **play precompile** command before starting the app.

**What folders do I deploy, which ones do I not deploy?**

app, conf and public. You might have some 3rd party lib dir too.

**Where on the target server hard drive do I place the webapp I'm deploying?**

I don't think it really matters.

**How do i tell apache where I deployed the play webapp to on the disk?**

Apache act as a reverse proxy (forwards every requests to your app and serves the reponses back to client). For this you need to [edit the apache's httpd.conf](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/production#SetupwithApache)

**How do I make it so that apache and play are now always running and don't require I be logged in on the target server?**

You need to start the apps as daemon threads which I think apache does by default. the command **play start** should run play in the background.

Comment: Thank you, you've helped a lot. So I've got apached wired up now to proxy requests to play, and I started play manually, but do i need to put that giant script file "play" inside the init.d folder? I find that without it, I can't run "chkconfig -add play" because the server doesn't recognize "play".

Comment: Because I started play manually, it won't be running if the machine is ever rebooted, so i need to fix that by adding it to the startup list, but as I mentioned "chkconfig --add play" isn't working unless I use that script i linked in my OP. But using that script, when play starts it throws errors. also of concern is to get play to "start" I had to specify an app. Well what if I want to run dozens of play apps on my server? Do I have to "play start " each one? I am still confused as to how to get this working like IIS where I host lots of sites and they are all running at startup.